# Download source code from Apple's website

Tags: macos, wget, apple-open-source

How do I download source code from Apple's website (http://opensource.apple.com/source/).
In particular, I am interested in http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55110/.

`wget -r` is downloading HTML files instead of source files. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, appending a `?txt` to the URL of any file seems to return the file in plain text. You might have to parse the HTML recursively to download files like this :(. I am surprised why isn't there a simple *Download tar.bz2* link anywhere! After all, opensource.apple.com does not seem to be entirely open :P

Answer (score 89):

I finally figured it out, sources can be conveniently downloaded from  http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/

Comment: This currently redirects to https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/.

Answer (score 6):

It can be downloaded directly from http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Security/Security-55110.tar.gz

Comment: It seems to be 2 different directories with open source projects: http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/ and https://opensource.apple.com/source/. How do you download from the 2nd link?

Answer (score 0):

You can download all apple open source code using [mkAppleOpenSourceDownload](https://github.com/mythkiven/mkAppleOpenSourceDownload)

Comment: This tool didn't work for me: https://github.com/mythkiven/mkAppleOpenSourceDownload/issues/2