# How to download a project folder from sourcecode.apple.com?

Tags: xcode, macos, repository, open-source, apple-open-source

If I'm looking at an Apple opensource page like this:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/Chess/

How can I download one of those projects to my hard drive so I can open it in XCode?

The main stumbling block for me is simply downloading one of the root folders (projects).

There is a [similar existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110146/download-source-code-from-apples-website), but it is specific to the "wget" utility (this question is more general) and its best answer only suggests [this official Apple OSS github repo](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions?q=&type=all&language=&sort=), but that *does NOT include all the projects contained within opensource.apple.com*, for example, it only contains the most recent version of chess, not ANY of the previous ones.

So, on opensource.apple.com, I cannot:

1. Right-click and select download, because the folders are just links to more HTML, not directly to files.
2. FTP to the url, because I don't have an FTP app installed on my Mac, and even if I did, I don't know if the Apple site would accommodate this.
3. Download each and every file one-by-one, recreating the local folder structure manually... because that seems foolish.

And as stated, while it is trivial to download from the Apple OSS github page, it doesn't contain the code I need!

I Googled this and surprisingly can't find anything.

So, is there a way to easily download from sourcecode.apple.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that's an older interface to access the open source code.

I went to https://opensource.apple.com/, clicked on the View Releases button which takes you to https://opensource.apple.com/releases/. There you can browse the separate projects. For example, to get the latest version of Chess, click on `macOS`, then `macOS 13.0`, then find `Chess-466.4.1`. There should be a download link and/or a link to the project on Github.

For instance, all open source projects for macOS 13.0: https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/distribution-macOS/tree/macos-130.

Comment: Thankyou! I couldn't figure that out.  I just posted a new question you may be interested in?