# How to Successfully Build the Open Source Apple Chess Game in XCode

Tags: c, objective-c, xcode, build, apple-open-source

I am trying to download and run the source code of a previous version of the [Apple macOS chess game](https://support.apple.com/guide/chess/welcome/mac) (preferably in the 369-408 version range) using XCode 14.1.

The game is written in Objective-C and interfaces with a chess engine called "sjeng" that is written in C.  (Correct me if I'm wrong).

I have already navigated some preliminary stumbling blocks (which you may want to follow to duplicate if you'd like to give this a try):

1. [Downloading the source code in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649589/how-to-download-a-project-folder-from-sourcecode-apple-com/74660326#74660326).

[ The next four steps come from [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673903) ]

2. Commenting out the "#include..." line from the Chess.xcconfig file.
3. Removing the com.apple.private.tcc.allow entitlement from the Chess.entitlements file.
4. Getting my provisioning profile set up for the X-Code project (this is straight-forward as long as you already have a developer profile).
5. Changing the bundle identifier from "com.apple..." to something random.
6. Resolving "Implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99" compile-time errors related to the C code within the sjeng chess engine.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850042/xcode-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-is-invalid-in-c99) helped with that.

But now I am stuck on the next and hopefully final step which is this is the build error:

```
./build-book normal nbook.pgn
+ test -z ''
+ SJENG=/Users/classified/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBChess-frynfmbcfskhcfdlqxxctvlldmnm/Build/Products/Development/sjeng.ChessEngine
+ cat
+ /Users/classified/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBChess-frynfmbcfskhcfdlqxxctvlldmnm/Build/Products/Development/sjeng.ChessEngine
./build-book: line 21: /Users/classified/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBChess-frynfmbcfskhcfdlqxxctvlldmnm/Build/Products/Development/sjeng.ChessEngine: No such file or directory
make: *** [nbook.db] Error 1
Command ExternalBuildToolExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have no clue what this stage of the build process pertains to.

I have verified in the Finder that the directory in the error message does indeed not exist.

I tried "Cleaning the Build Folder" in XCode and building again, but same result.

*Can anyone get the game actually running (from source) on macOS and describe the steps required to get there?*

Comment: The error concerns a missing file. I have no idea but I would **guess** that file was supposed to be generated in an earlier step of the build process which also failed. The path name element `DerivedData` is a bit of a clue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how it worked for me:

1. Download the project from [here (build tag 408)](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/Chess/archive/Chess-408.tar.gz);
2. Unarchive the project and open `MBChess.xcodeproj` file with Xcode;
3. Open `MBChess` target and do as follows:

   - Change Bundle Identifier to something more relevant to you
   - Enable "Automatically manage signing" flag
   - Choose your Apple Developer team OR choose any personal team
   - (Optional) If you chose a personal team, don't forget to remove incompatible entitlements from here (Game Center)

[image]

4. Remove `Chess.xcconfig` file from Project Navigator:
   [image]
5. Find `Chess.entitelements` file and remove `com.apple.private.tcc.allow` array from it:
   [image]
6. Select `sjeng` target and build it first
   [image]
7. Select `MBChess` target and build it for the same platform
   [image]

At this point the app should build successfully (I was using macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400) as the target platform with Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b))

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!  I think the main thing was compiling sjeng separately first.  I think this will be very useful for others in the future, also.

Comment: @NerdyBunz In fact this dependency is set under `MBChess` target and theoretically `sjen` should have been compiled first automatically. However the same dependency exist for another target `Opening Books` which itself also depends on `sjen`. For some reason `Opening books` dependency was not satisfied for me in the given order either, and it started working for me only after i built `sjen` manually. For future reference - you can find which targets are expected to be built before an arbitrary target under `Target Dependencies` phase of `Build Phases` (provided the dependencies were specified)