# Is Apple Foundation open source?

Tags: foundation

MacOS calls its core libraries Foundation. This includes a class that stores cookies on the system called [`HTTPCookieStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiestorage). Is the source code for this class available anywhere for the public? Or are we only ever given a header file?

Comment: @Chris that's a different question, entirely. This question is about how source the other one is about whether or not it's distributed as a shared object (binary) or statically linked into the rest of the system. Please don't assume a question with the same tag asked by the user is the same, simply read it.

Comment: I did read both questions. They're very similar, asked by the same user (you) only an hour apart, and seem to be driving at the same thing. In my opinion, this is a dupe.

Comment: What does the asker, and the duration between questions have to do with anything. Answer: nothing. More words don't give you any reason. They're "similar" because they have the same tag, I granted you that much in my original reply and I'll grant it again and nothing more, at all.

Comment: If I ask you how glibc is distributed by Debian the answer is as a compiled shared object file which typically dynamically link in by the distro when it's compiled. You typically find it as `libc.so` and on Debian it's `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`. That's _distribution_. If I ask you where you can find the source the source code for it, I would say, for Debian, by using `apt-get source libc6` or upstream it's in https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html

Comment: These are totally 99.9% different questions. Having the same tag, and originating from the same person -- even if at the same time -- does not make a question a dupe.

Comment: 99.9% is a bit of a stretch. In any case, we're both entitled to our opinions and arguing in the comments isn't very productive.

Comment: How is this question closed but the much more vague question isn't closed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110146/

Answer (score 0):

Apple has open-sourced some of its projects and components, but typically, they don't make the entire operating system or core frameworks like Foundation open source. You can find open-source projects related to Apple at Apple's official GitHub page https://github.com/apple, but these projects often do not include core components like Foundation.